# ngx-toastr.js?4996:264 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function at eval (ngx-toastr.js?4996:264)

Tags: ngx-toastr

I am using ngx-toastr in angular 6 for http error notification, as injected ToastrService in httpInterceptor

```
    export class MyInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
        constructor(public toasterService: ToastrService) { }

        intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
            return next.handle(request)
                .pipe(
                    tap((evt: any) => {
                        if (evt instanceof HttpResponse) {
                            if (evt.body)
                                this.toasterService.success('success', '!!', { positionClass: 'toast-bottom-center' });
                                //alert(`success`);

                        }
                    }),
                    catchError((err: any) => {                    
                        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                            try {
                                this.toasterService.error(err.error.message, err.error.title, { positionClass: 'toast-bottom-center' });

                            } catch (e) {
                                this.toasterService.error('An error occurred', '', { positionClass: 'toast-bottom-center' });

                            }
                            //log error 
                        }
                        return of(err);
 })
            )
    }
}
```

and imported ToastrModule in app.module.ts like

```
imports:[
ToastrModule.forRoot()
]
```

I am getting below error, any idea whats going wrong here..............

> ngx-toastr.js?4996:264 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a
>   function
>       at eval (ngx-toastr.js?4996:264)   .................................

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I found the actual issue regarding this. It's happening because of the mismatch of the version of an angular and the package. To overcome this problem perform the following steps

**STEP1**: Check for angular CLI version: `ng --version`

Now check this image

[image]

If your angular version is **7.3.10** then you need to install **10.1.0** version of **ngx-toastr**

[image]

**STEP2**: Install a specific version of **ngx-toastr** according to your angular CLI version:  `npm i ngx-toastr@10.1.0 --save`

**STEP3**: import it into `app.module.ts`

**app.module.ts**

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
 
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
 
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule, // required animations module
    ToastrModule.forRoot() // ToastrModule added
  ],
  bootstrap: [App],
  declarations: [App]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

**STEP4**: add **css** path in **styles** array in `angular.json` file

**angular.json**

```
"styles": [
    "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
    "src/styles/app.scss",
    "node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css",
    "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css"
]
```

Don't forget to restart your server after making changes in `angular.json` file

**STEP5**: make helper service to show toasters

**helper.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class HelperService {
    constructor(private toastr: ToastrService) { };

    showSuccessToast(msg) {
        this.toastr.success(msg);
    }

    showErrorToast(msg) {
        this.toastr.error(msg);
    }

    showInfoToast(msg) {
        this.toastr.info(msg);
    }
}
```

**STEP6**: Now you are done you just need to use these functions in your `component.ts` file

**user.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { routerTransition } from '../../router.animations';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { HelperService } from 'src/app/helpers/helper.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.scss'],
  animations: [routerTransition()]
})

export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    private helperService: HelperService,
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  async getUsers() {
    try {
      const res: any = await this.userService.getUsers();
      this.helperService.showSuccessToast(res.message);
    } catch (err) {
      this.helperService.showErrorToast(err.error || 'Something went wrong');
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: As per the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr#setup), only add the css to the json file if you're on Angular < 6, otherwise add the following to your style.css `@import '~ngx-toastr/toastr';`

Comment: Refer to the official docs for the latest dependencies. The image attached above has changed since.